# Stash and database replication

Tags: stash, database

We are running **EE 2** and **Stash**, 2 DB's: 1 master, 1 slave. The master-slave relationship keeps breaking with the following error:

> CRITICAL - Slave sql is not running. Last error: Could not execute
>   Delete_rows_v1 event on table co_site.exp_stash: Can't find record in
>   'exp_stash', Error_code: 1032: handler error HA_ERR_KEY_NOT_FOUND: the
>   event's master log mysql-master-db-binlog.000001, end_log_pos 55763226

My question is two-fold:
1. Should tables exp_stash and exp_stash_bundles be replicated?
2. If they should, has this issue come up before and is there a fix that will allow our replication working without these errors?

Many Thanks,

Studio1057

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't think there's anything special about those two tables with regard to MySQL.  If you are doing replication on the other tables then these should be replicated as well.

Is it possible that you are doing some delete operation on *the slave* without meaning to?  (perhaps some kind of script to clear caches or something?)

Comment: It is almost like if stash pruning is happening on the slave database, even though all web servers are pointing to the master.

Comment: I believe such an action would be logged.  You might want to ask for details of how to track this down on a different Stack.

Answer (score 0):

Stash is a cache plugin for EE. The solution is to exclude it from replication:

replicate-ignore-table = [your_database].exp_stash

This will inhibit this table from replicating. It cannot be done on the binlog level on the master unless the stash has it's own database.